# Why does four Apple Model Numbers (A1457, A1518, A1528 & A1530) have two FCC IDs (BCG‑E2643A & BCG‑E2643B)

Tags: identification, iphone, fcc

These are model Numbers of iPhone 5S.
I want to know why two Model numbers of iPhones have the same FCC ID?
I am assuming that as they are two models, they are NOT the same for Apple yet they have the same FCC ID . 
What constitutes a change of FCC ID and when does it take place?

Another example would be of iPhone 5 where Models A1428, A1429 and A1442 have the same FCC ID BCG‑E2599A.

Why so?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with electronic design and should be closed.

Comment: Complying with regulatory standards has nothing to do with electronic design? :)

Comment: Apple does that because they can. So they do. What use is this information to you anyway ?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Information about FCC regulations could be quite useful for many people. While I don't directly deal with FCC regulations I find this question interesting and would like to know the answer for future reference.

Comment: None of these are for the US market, so why do they even have a FCC ID?

Comment: @Passerby All of these are there in the US market as far as I know.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie apple has a process and has reasons to get a different FCC ID. paying $20k isn't something i think Apple would want to do just because they can.

Comment: @FahimKazi A1530 is Asia Pacific market, A1528 is china unicom, a1518 is china mobile, a1457 is Europe/Middle East, and A1442 is China Telecom. Only a1428 and a1429 are US market, though they have international versions too.

Comment: @Passerby oh I didn't know that. they are still given FCC IDs though. Is there a source where I can see which iPhones are made for which regions by Model number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the impression that Apple has done testing of different functions on multiple hardware with similarities.

From FCC:

[image]

The FCC IDs applies to different frequencies. Could be the Wifi / Bluetooth module is tested and filed under one number for a specific model, but the radio was tested on another model.

From 2643B test report:
[image]
Hints of similarities with 2643A except for the Wifi.

Usually similarity is used so you don't have to retest every configuration (memory, battery, etc) of a hardware. But the exact definition of similarity probably have to be discussed with FCC.